# The virtual path ... maps to another application, which is not allowed. Team Foundation Server build fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, continuous-integration

I have a WebSite project that builds successfully when running locally. I'm trying to setup Continuous Builds for this website in TFS (Visual Studio 2010) - when the build runs, it's failing with this error -

The virtual path '/abc/MasterPages/abc.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Within my build agent, I'm not even trying to publish this to IIS - all I've configured it to do is to just run the build and copy the output to a specific folder.

Can anyone please let me know how I can get around this problem in TFS, as the same code runs successfully on all the developers' workstations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around was to Prefix ~ in all relative URLs - for eg: '/abc/MasterPages/abc.master' will be '~/abc/MasterPages/abc.master'

That seemed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have publish information set as part of the project? If so remove it. Publish step needs to be done another way as part of a tfs build